# The server could not process the request : ClassFactory cannot provide the requested class

Tags: windows, vb6, regedit, class-factory

I am currently testing an asmx web service methode via SoapUI, first i got this error :
**the server could not process the request the object with the CLSID is invalid or not registered.**

So i exported the missing CLSID from another server containing the dll registred with the correct CLSID, and now when i run the request i get this error :
**the server could not process the request : ClassFactory cannot provide the requested class**

I did some research on the web including stackoverflow, but still facing the issue if someone got an idea...

**The webservice is hosted on WindowsXp**

Comment: What have you exported? Registry entries? Without the corresponding dll (and possible dependencies) the registry entries alone won't work. How is VB6 involved? How and what kind of webservice is hosted? You'll need to provide more details.

Comment: I copied the same dll file, but registered with a different CLSID, so once i copied it, then i exported the corresponding regedit key. 
The web service is hosted on the IIS server and the code call some ActiveX components that are developed in VB6
Thank you

Comment: You can't change the CLSIDs of ActiveX components without changing the corresponding DLL. The original dll doesn't know anything about your CLSID.

Comment: Just using `regsvr32 your.dll` will get you all CLSIDs in the registry for you -- no need to copy anything.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I did, first to make sure I'm using the corresponding CLSID DLL, I copied it from another server, but what is strange is that I have a new version of the dll file and it's registered with a different CLSID, but the code is looking for another key (old CLSID)

Comment: Sounds like the local DLL you have registered is not a match for the expected version. If these are VB6 DLLs they should be compiled with binary or at least project compatibility.